# Mysql prepared statement LIKE issue

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make a live search form where whenever the user types a letter an ajax function is called and searches database for results

Ajax is called successfully but, my only problem is that my query works as if it is WHERE col = value not LIKE, I have to type the col full name to get a result or else I don't get any result.
Here is my php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$tagname = $_POST['search'];
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(tagid) FROM sectags WHERE sectags.tagid = tags.tagid) FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $tagname);
$stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $tag, $imghref, $tagcount);
echo '<ul>';


while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <!-- Creating unordered list items.
         Calling javascript function named as "fill" found in "script.js" file.
         By passing fetched result as parameter. -->
    <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $tag ?>")'>
        <a>
            <!-- Assigning searched result in "Search box" in "search.php" file. -->
            <?php echo $tag; ?>
    </li></a>
    <?php
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
```

Other selected parameters from database will be used later tho.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the wildcards into the value you bind to the parameter to make `LIKE` work properly e.g.

```
$tagname = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';
```